# Solving limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}}{x}$, without using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've been asked to find the limit, without using L'hospital's rule, of:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}}{x}$$

Here's my attempt:
$$\begin{aligned}&\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(2x)}}{x}\\=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2(x)}}{x}\\=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(x)}{x}\\=&\sqrt{2}\end{aligned}$$

So my question is what's the problem here? The graph shows that limit doesn't exist. In which situations do we have to find LHL and RHL?

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}$ does not equal $\sin(x)$. It equals $|\sin(x)|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the equality $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=\sin(x)$, which is false. What you have is $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|$ instead. And you have$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|\sin x|}x=1\quad\text{whereas}\quad\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{|\sin x|}x=-1.$$